# My rails app is auto redirecting to https from http in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl-certificate

My Rails application is working fine on dev mode.
In production mode the localhost:3000 is also opening nicely(with http), but on clicking signup link,

```
it's auto redirecting to "https://localhost/signup".
```

In production.rb file, i have marked

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

still it's auto redirecting to https from http.

Few links are working fine, where as in others the url is appended with https and no content is visible. 
There is no trace in log/terminal for this issue.
I am using Rails 4.

Comment: how are you serving this app in production?

Comment: rails s -e production

Comment: Can you show us an example of template code for a link that's redirecting to https and a link that is not ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Do this to find out if you are enforcing HTTPS in your controller or routes.

```
$ git grep force_ssl app/controllers
$ git grep https config/routes.rb
```

Comment: project is not in GIT. it's in local machine.
searched for ssl in complete project, found it in production.rb which is also set to false. No trace of any ssl in other files.

Comment: the project really should be in git, or some form of version control.

Comment: run grep without git before in that case